# Struts2 on Eclipse

Tags: jquery, eclipse, struts

I am starting a project on Struts2 which also includes JPA, Postgres, Jquery and Jquery-ui. Can you tell me which plugins for Eclipse will be best suited for this kind of development.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you use maven2 eclipse integration plugin to build your project and to aquire  your dependencies
I also recommend the following struts2 plugins 
1- struts2 and struts2 full hibernate plugin found on code.google.com
2- struts2 jquery plugin also found on code.google.com